# Converting a graph in networkx to an array of degree of nodes?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

A beginner in this area here.

I am looking to to make a function which takes input as a graph and returns an array with degree of all nodes like

[1 2 3 
4 5 2]

corresponding to 1st node having a degree of 1..?

I have made a function that returns a graph. 
Now I want to use this graph and return an array.

Is there a way to convert a graph with a built in function? I tried numpy_to_matrix but that doesn't work.

Comment: `networkx.degree(graph)` or `graph.degree` (IIRC)

Comment: Thanks. What does IIRC stand for?

Comment: If I recall correctly